Jenkins error Component should create FAILED, Error: Found the synthetic property @.disabled
I hit the error as mentioned in the title during Jenkins build when npmTest is true:
Component should create FAILED, Error: Found the synthetic property @.disabled. Please include either "BrowserAnimationsModule" or "NoopAnimationsModule" in your application. in vendor.js
but the application is able to deploy without any issue  if npmTest is false.
Why does this happen, since I already imported the BrowserAnimationsModule in my app.module.ts, and I don't see any usage of @.disabled in my code, so I am not sure why this error show up in Jenkins.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
